# CSS - relative element hides another

Tags: html, css

I have few `<table>` elements. I'm styling them with only one css property `position: relative;` to show some extra info which you can see on my screen. However if two table elements are styled, one of them is getting hidden by another and I don't know why. I could use  `z-index: 1;` for one on left side, but I believe it's not the best way to solve it. I've tried overflow and visibility properties, but none of them is working.

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBAE6.jpg)

Comment: Show us some code. Read this: [mcve]

Comment: Can you please post your code so we can help you in the right direction?

Comment: try using `z-index: 999;`?

Comment: But if I would use same z-index on both elements, the first will be still hidden by another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that we need you to share your code, so we can identify where the problem is. But I'll try to help you out.

I'll assume from your image that you are using a `position: relative` container, for the blue stripe that is `position: absolute`, right?

In this case, remove the `z-index` from the relative elements, and set it only on the `position: absolute` ones, as you can see on the example bellow. Hope it helps:

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="relative">
      <div class="absolute"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="relative">
      <div class="absolute"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, the thing was to add same high z-index to the absolute element, now nothing is hidden by another.